# Add SSL certificate to rails site, apache2 passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, apache2, ssl-certificate, passenger

I have a linux server running Ubuntu 10.04, apache2 and passenger. Its a 1and1 package and comes with an SSL certificate which has the various .crt and .key files present in /etc/ssl.

I have 3 apps hosted on this server, only 1 of which needs SSL encryption. All of the apps are run as a SubURI, e.g. domain.com/app1, domain.com/app2 etc etc and have symlinks created in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled.

How could I get app3 to use the SSL certificate whilst still remaning under a subURI of the server?

Thanks in advance!

apache2.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName domain.eu
DocumentRoot /var/www
<Directory /var/www>
Allow from all
</Directory>


RailsBaseURI /app1
<Directory /apps/app1/public>
Options -MultiViews
</Directory>

RailsBaseURI /app2
<Directory /apps/app2/public>
Options -MultiViews
</Directory>

RailsBaseURI /app3
<Directory /apps/app3/public>
Options -MultiViews
</Directory>
```

Comment: Are you using Debian-like OS? Firstly add mod_ssl apache module through apt-get.

Comment: Hi Webbandit, im using ubuntu 10.04. Will this enable me to add a another virtualhost config listening on port :443 to the above example?

Comment: Yes it will allow you to do so.